# How to get the Sum of my Units Sold based on an Item sold with other Items

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to write a query using the following logic:

I have an Item Table where all transactions are stored by different site location and business date, I also have a key for each order stored. Now, my item table looks as below:

```
SiteID   BusinessDate   ItemName   Units Sold   Units Sale   ItemNo  OrderNo
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        06/08/2018     Apple         1             5        10001    122-1
1        06/08/2018     Coffee        1             16       10002    122-1
1        06/08/2018     Bread         2             7        10003    122-1
1        06/08/2018     Beans         9             18       10004    122-1

1        06/08/2018     Apple         2             5        10001    122-4
1        06/08/2018     Coffee        2             6        10002    122-4
1        06/08/2018     Bread         1             7        10003    122-4
1        06/08/2018     Beans         4             8        10004    122-4

2        06/08/2018     Apple         2             5        10001    122-2
2        06/08/2018     Coffee        1             6        10002    122-2

3        06/08/2018     Bread         3             5        10003    122-3
3        06/08/2018     Beans         7             17       10004    122-3
```

Now I want to get the output, if a user select a base item which is "10001" then it should calculate the values of Units Sold for all items that was sold along with that order excluding the base Item itself which in my case is "10001"

so the final output should look something like this:

```
SiteID   BusinessDate   Item Code  Itemname    Units Sold   Units Sale
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        06/08/2018     10001       Apple           3        62
2        06/08/2018     10001       Apple           2        6
3        06/08/2018     10001       Apple           0        0
```

Units Sold = total units of my base item which is "10001" on siteID = 1

Units Sale = total units sales of all other items purchased along with my based item excluding the unit sale value of my base item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method would be to use `CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY`. This can be simplified a little if you don't need SiteID 3 in your result set.

```
DECLARE @itemNo INT

SET @itemNo = 10001

SELECT tmp.*, ca.*, oa.UnitsSold, CASE WHEN oa.UnitsSold = 0 THEN 0 ELSE oa.UnitsSale END AS UnitsSale
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SiteID, BusinessDate FROM YourTable) tmp
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT ItemNo, ItemName FROM YourTable WHERE ItemNo = @itemNo) ca
OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ItemNo = @itemNo THEN [Units Sold] ELSE 0 END) AS UnitsSold,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN ItemNo != @itemNo THEN [Units Sale] ELSE 0 END) AS UnitsSale
             FROM YourTable
             WHERE SiteID = tmp.SiteID AND BusinessDate = tmp.BusinessDate) oa
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the same, One concern I have also, if have a master list of my base items for example "10001,1002,10003" will it be possible with the same above query to return the said result?!

Comment: If you replace the 10001 in the where statement with 10002 or 10003, you'll get the results for Coffee or Bread instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```html
Select SiteID,BusinessDate,ItemNo,MAX(Itemname) AS Itemname,SUM(Units Sold) As Units Sold,SUM(Units Sale) As Units Sale
Group By SiteID, BusinessDate, ItemNo
```

Comment: He didn't ask for a simple sum of UnitsSale, he wants to exclude some records.

Comment: this query gives exactly the same output

Comment: Did you run it, sum of UnitsSale will be 10 when grouped by ItemNo not 62.